# Python 3 - Splitting a PDF file

Tags: python-3.x, pypdf

I'm hoping to extract pages 30 to 34 from my PDF file and make it into a single doc. However, my code seems to only get me page 34.

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

path = 'file_path'

pdf = PdfFileReader(path, "rb")

for page in range(29, 33):
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
    pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(page))

output_fname = "Output.pdf"

with open(output_fname, 'wb') as out:
    pdf_writer.write(out)

print ("PDF file has been split")
```

Okay I've noticed if I changed the middle part of the code to add the pages manually it works. But I do need a less clunky way of doing it for extracting a large number of pages.

```
output.addPage(pdf.getPage(29))
output.addPage(pdf.getPage(30))
```

Answer (score 3):

Nvm I realise my error. Should've just excluded the pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter() from the loop statement.

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

path = 'file_path'
pdf = PdfFileReader(path, "rb")

pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()

for page in range(29, 33):
    pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(page))

output_fname = "Output.pdf"

with open(output_fname, 'wb') as out:
    pdf_writer.write(out)

print ("PDF file has been split")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

path = r"C:\Users\scriptdocuchm_ktm.pdf"

pdf = PdfFileReader(path, "rb")
pdflist = []
pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()

for page in range(66,70):
    pdflist.append(page)
    pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(page))

print(pdflist)

output_filename = "split.pdf"

with open(output_filename, 'wb') as out:
    pdf_writer.write(out)

print ("pdf file has been split")
```

Comment: Please add some text describing what your code is doing

Comment: I think this would be enough simple